# When and why does Curator throw ConnectionLossException?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I use Curator 1.2.4 and I keep getting `ConnectionLossException` when I want to monitor one znode for its children's changes.

I then implemented a watcher like this

```java
public class CuratorChildWatcherImpl implements CuratorWatcher {

    private CuratorFramework client;

    public CuratorChildWatcherImpl(CuratorFramework client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(WatchedEvent event) throws Exception {
       List<String> children=client.getChildren().usingWatcher(this).forPath(event.getPath());
       // Do other stuff with the children znode.
    }
}
```

Every 11 seconds the code throws `ConnectionLossException` if `connectionTimeout` is set to 10 seconds. It seems the exception is `connectionTimeout` plus 1 second. Why?

I checked the source code found that GetChildrenBuilderImpl will call the CuratorZookeeperClient's blockUntilConnectedOrTimeout method which will check the connection state every 1 second.

```
2013-04-17 17:22:08 [ERROR]-[com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:97)] Connection timed out for connection string (...) and timeout (10000) / elapsed (10317913)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:94)
    at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:107)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:413)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:213)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:202)
    at com.netflix.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:106)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:198)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:190)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:37)
    at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:56)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:521)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a known bug in the Curator/ZooKeeper interaction that's tracked under [CURATOR-24 The current method of managing hung ZK handles needs improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-24). It was fixed in 2.0.1-incubating version.

Comment: Thanks @Randgalt, I sent you some emails and you already told me that. Sorry for not updating this question.